# Twitter bootstrap columns not displaying as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded the latest release of TB, and have just started fto familiarize myself with it. As my very first test, I wanted to create a page with 2 columns, the first column would be 2/3 the content area, and the second column would consume the remaining 1/3 of the available space.

I am assuming that the content area is 12 columns wide as the documentation states. This is the simple code snippet I have in the content area of my page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4" style="border: 1px red solid;"></div>
    <div class="span8" style="border: 1px blue solid;"></div>
</div>
```

When the column width sums as to 12, the columns are stacked on top of each other, instead of being side by side as I expected (from reading the docs). If the sum of the column widths are less than 12, then the columns are stacked side by side as expected.

Why is this happening?

**[[Edit]]**

I just had a look at the TB css definitions for the span classes I am using. They are:

```
.span4 {
    width: 370px;
}

.span8 {
    width: 770px;
}
```

It appears that is wrong for my display (1366 x 768).

What can I do to fix it, so that I have the layout I want (2/3 1st col, 1/3 2nd col)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your elements are bigger than expected. Exactly they are 4 px longer(1px for each left and right bodrder).

Comment: Hmm, not sure where you are getting that from - is it somewhere in the docs?. Also, how then can I split a layout in the way I want to do? Thanks.

Comment: As a workaround you can add next for each span*: `margin: 0 -1px;`

Comment: When you write `border: 1px red solid;` your element becomes longer for 2px and higher for 2px - that's CSS basics. I'm going to find link on article for you

Comment: Ah, I see  -of course I'm such a fool :/. I forgot I was adding a width in the border in my style. Excuse my stupidity SMDH!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to edit your css and and change the body/container width to a higher number?